# Clarifying a custom Rails 3.0 Validation with methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, readability

I've created a custom validator in Rails 3.0 which validates whether a combination of columns is unique within a table.  The entire code of the validation is:

```
class UniqueInProjectValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless object.class.where("project_id = ? AND #{attribute} = ?", object.project_id, value).empty?
      if object.new_record?
        object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must be unique in each project")
      else
        orig_rec = object.class.find(object.id)
        if value != orig_rec.method(attribute).call || object.project_id != orig_rec.project_id
          object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must be unique in each project")
        end
      end
    end

end
```

Note that it is not easy to recognize what the if statements do, so I was hoping to be able to replace the `unless` conditional with a `def attribute_and_project_exist?` method and the second `if` statement with a `def attribute_or_project_changed?` method.  However when creating those methods, the arguments from `validates_each` do not pass because of encapsulation.

Now the question: Is there a way to somehow cleanly allow those variables to be accessed by my two newly created methods as one can do with column names in a model, or am I stuck with the options of either passing each argument again or leaving the hard to read conditional statements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could clean it up a bit with one variable, one lambda, and one "return as soon as possible":

```ruby
def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
  # If there is no duplication then bail out right away as
  # there is nothing to check. This reduces your nesting by
  # one level. Using a variable here helps to make your
  # intention clear.
  attribute_and_project_exists = object.class.where("project_id = ? AND #{attribute} = ?", object.project_id, value).empty?
  return unless attribute_and_project_exists

  # This lambda wraps up your second chunk of ugly if-ness and saves
  # you from computing the result unless you have to.
  attribute_or_project_changed = lambda do
    orig_rec = object.class.find(object.id)
    value != orig_rec.method(attribute).call || object.project_id != orig_rec.project_id
  end

  # Note that || short-circuits so the lambda will only be 
  # called if you have an existing record.
  if object.new_record? || attribute_or_project_changed.call
    object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must be unique in each project")
  end
end
```

I don't know how much better that is than your original but the logic and control flow is a lot clearer to me due to the nicer chunking.

Comment: Interesting way to do change the code.  It seems that no processing time is lost this way, and I would get to use the naming conventions I like for clarity.  My only reservation is that it doesn't feel very rails-y.  That said, I still think I'll adopt this version over mine, unless something even slicker comes by.  Thanks mu!

Comment: @Manocho: I have pretty wide and varied language/environment/... background so my take on things might be different that someone that eats and breaths Rails; for example, I don't see lambdas used that much in Rails code but that could just be the code that I look at. Optimize for clarity first, don't worry about how fast it is until (a) you have a performance problem and (b) you know (via profiling) where it is.